# add more nav links if admin is logged in

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to add one more nav link to my navbar that will appear if the logged in user is an admin.

```
 <?php
        require("config.php");
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if($conn->connect_error){
            die("connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);
        }
        session_start(); 
        echo "welcome " . $_SESSION['login_user'];

        $user=$_SESSION['login_user'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);     

    ?>

<body>
  <?
if ($user=="admin"){
  ?>
<div class="topnav">
 <a href="Home.php">Home</a>
 <a href="cart.php"> orders </a>
 <a href="login.php">Login </a>
 <a href="account.php">My Account </a>
 <a href="admin.php">Admin </a>;
    <?
   }
?>
</div>
```

this is what i have at the moment and its not working event though `$user`prints the actual value

Comment: you set $user before the query....

Comment: not working means what? It prints the extra links? Or not? What is the value of `$user` at that time? Did you ever set this session value anywhere beforehand? And what is the purpose of your SQL query? You never use any of the values from it. It's not really clear what the issue is.

Comment: it will print the extra link regardless, $user value was admin and the SQL query is used for something else in same page @ADyson

Comment: so when the $user value is _not_ "admin"...then what happens? From what I can see it should not output that extra HTML. It looks fine.

Comment: it will still print the extra link no matter what $user value is @ADyson

Comment: Just replace your `<?` with  `<?php` for me please...maybe you have short-open-tags switched off. If that's the case it simply won't run your `if` statement.

Comment: It worked!! @ADyson

Comment: @N3B1 Great. I added it as the answer, for you to mark as "accepted" when you have a moment (you should click the tick mark next to the answer so that it turns green). Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your PHP short open tags

```
<?
```

with full tags:

```
<?php
```

The short format will not work unless you have `short_open_tag` set to `On` in your php.ini file. Consequently, any PHP code, such as your `if` statement which is within such a short tag will not be executed.